# What is the correct way to initialize data in a lookup table using DBFlow?

Tags: android, dbflow

I am trying to implement DBFlow for the first time and I think I might just not get it. I am not an advanced Android developer, but I have created a few apps. In the past, I would just create a "database" object that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, then override the callback methods.

In onCreate, once all of the tables have been created, I would populate any lookup data with a hard-coded SQL string: `db.execSQL(Interface.INSERT_SQL_STRING);`. Because I'm lazy, in `onUpgrade()` and `onDowngrade()`, I would just DROP the tables and call `onCreate(db);`.

I have read through the migrations documentation, which not only seems to be outdated syntactically because "database =" has been changed to "databaseName =" in the annotation, but also makes no mention of migrating from no database to version "initial". I found an [issue](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/160) that claims that migration 0 can be used for this purpose, but I cannot get any migrations to work at this point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The project is @ [Github](https://github.com/daweber/Brackets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below is correct, but I believe that this Answer and Question will soon be "deprecated" along with most third-part ORMs. Google's new [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) ([Yigit's Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfHsPGQ6bgE)) will be preferred in most cases. Although DBFlow will certainly carry on (Thank You [Andrew](https://github.com/agrosner)) in many projects, here is a good place to re-direct people to the newest "best practice" because this particular question was/is geared for those new to DBFlow.

The correct way to initialize the database (akin to the SQLiteOpenHelper's `onCreate(db)` callback is to create a [Migration object](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/master/usage2/Migrations.md) that extends [BaseMigration](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/blob/3cf45133b0bee1b942d14e3cf1e065da7ed7387d/dbflow/src/main/java/com/raizlabs/android/dbflow/sql/migration/BaseMigration.java) with the `version=0`, then add the following to the `onCreate()` in the Application class (or wherever you are doing the DBFlow initialization):

```
FlowManager.init(new FlowConfig.Builder(this).build());
FlowManager.getDatabase(BracketsDatabase.NAME).getWritableDatabase();
```

In the Migration Class, you override the `migrate()` and then you can use the Transaction manager to initialize lookup data or other initial database content.

**Migration Class:**

```
@Migration(version = 0, database = BracketsDatabase.class)
public class DatabaseInit extends BaseMigration {
    private static final String TAG = "classTag";

@Override
public void migrate(DatabaseWrapper database) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Init Data...");
    populateMethodOne();
    populateMethodTwo();
    populateMethodThree();
    Log.d(TAG, "Data Initialized");
}
```

To populate the data, use your models to create the records and the Transaction Manager to save the models via `FlowManager.getDatabase(AppDatabase.class).getTransactionManager()
  .getSaveQueue().addAll(models);`

Answer (score 0):

To initialize data in DBFlow all you have to do is create a class for your object models that extends `BaseModel` and use the `@Table` annotation for the class.

Then create some objects of that class and call `.save()` on them.

You can check the examples in [the library's documentation](https://github.com/agrosner/DBFlowDocs/blob/master/GettingStarted.md).

Comment: I know of several ways to get the data into the table, including create a new object and `.save()`ing it, but I'm not exactly sure which method is "correct", and when (or where) to do it. I could put the lookup data in a Array, then loop through, creating and saving each record, but I think this type of framework is created to avoid that type of hackery.

Comment: There is also a group save:
      `TransactionManager.getInstance().saveOnSaveQueue(yourObjectCollection);`

Comment: If you want to fill your database with initial data, you can do that on your migration class.